# Phonegap 3.0,Cordova CLI: an error occurred during creation of ios sub-project

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova

An Error is showing when I running the Android Project using Phonegap 3.0 in Command Line Interface
(Phonegap local run android)

Cordova CLI: an error occurred during creation of ios sub-project,The system can not find the path specified.

I have also tried the following steps 
$ cordova create HelloWorld com.example.hello "Hello World"

Then try removing the whitespace between Hello World.
$ cordova create HelloWorld com.example.hello "HelloWorld"

Then It was giving the same error.

D:\Applications\TestApp1>Phonegap local run android
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. The system cannot find the path specified.

Please suggest

Comment: Try running `phonegap local build android -V` for verbose output.

Comment: Do you need to use `phonegap create HelloWorld` instead of `cordova`?

Answer (score 1):

**[solved]**
if you are using windows.
don't forget to install jdk. you can found it at [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

try to follow this instruction on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjtwinM1m_0) . 
and for the detail instruction you can follow the phonegap get started page.

next, install the sdk android first. goto developer*android*com/sdk/index.html to download the package. furthermore extract them, and open the "sdk manager" at your path. install more package of API's as you needs.

i recommend to install gingerbread(2.3) api 10 and ICS(4.0) version.

on this progress install ant package you may found a trouble same as me. but don't worry, I've found the answer.

just follow this instruction on youtube*com/watch?v=bAbBqrTG3q4 . by using my package on drive*google*com/file/d/0B4B3LaTbByxAWlVpQjJhSjd5dVU/edit?usp=sharing .

if you still have an error, you can call me on YM : rifqi_platinum25.

note: change [*] with [.] to access the page. i'm sorry for inconvenience because i haven't at least 10 reputation to post with over 2 links. thank's.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a problem of creating a new project. You can try it by changing the location as `cordova create ../HelloWorld com.example.hello "HelloWorld"`

Comment: My issue has been resovled------

Comment: Previously I was using

Comment: npm config set proxy http://localhost:8999 Use below command in Node.js
npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:8999